# Why Heroku deployment is showing H10 error

Tags: node.js, heroku

I tried several answers and it seems not to work, keep showing the **H10 error** **status 503** **ReferenceError document is not defined** while developing to heroku.

**Here is my folder:**
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh7Ik.png)

**Here is Procfile:**

```
web: node server.js
```

**Here is my package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "natours",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Learning node, express and mongoDB",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js",
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js",
    "debug": "ndb server.js",
    "watch:js": "parcel serve --no-hmr ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js/bundled",
    "build": "parcel build ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js/bundled"
  },
  "author": "Jonas",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-mongo-sanitize": "^2.2.0",
    "express-rate-limit": "^6.4.0",
    "helmet": "^5.1.0",
    "hpp": "^0.2.3",
    "html-to-text": "^8.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.4",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "sharp": "^0.30.7",
    "slugify": "^1.6.5",
    "speakeasy": "^2.0.0",
    "stripe": "^9.16.0",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "xss-clean": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "parcel": "^2.6.2",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

**Here is my server.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// Uncaught exceptions (not
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log('UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION! Shutting down...');
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  process.exit(1);
});

// enviroments variables
dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' }); //read from file and save to nodejs enviroment variable

const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  '<PASSWORD>',
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

// Connect to database
mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    // useUnifiedTopology: true,
    // useCreateIndex: true,  //not supported
    // useFindAndModify: false, //not supported
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('==============================');
  });

const app = require('./app');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.set('host', '0.0.0.0');
const SERVER = app.listen(PORT, app.get('host'), () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${PORT}`);
});

// Unhandled Rejections
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  console.log('UNHANDLED REJECTION! Shutting down the server ...');
  SERVER.close(() => {
    process.exit(1);
  });
});
```

**Here is the error log:**

> 2022-07-31T14:23:29.999646+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> crashed to starting 2022-07-31T14:23:33.596871+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
> Starting process with command `node server.js`
> 2022-07-31T14:23:34.578370+00:00 app[web.1]: Hello from Parcel
> 2022-07-31T14:23:34.578926+00:00 app[web.1]: UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION!
> Shutting down... 2022-07-31T14:23:34.578963+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ReferenceError document is not defined
> 2022-07-31T14:23:34.692639+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1 2022-07-31T14:23:34.748437+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
> from starting to crashed 2022-07-31T16:52:50.967106+00:00
> heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
> path="/" host=enigmatic-bayou-09078.herokuapp.com
> request_id=833fb548-e284-4d45-8258-bc7f195c1885 fwd="213.225.8.56"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-07-31T16:52:51.183535+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
> host=enigmatic-bayou-09078.herokuapp.com
> request_id=d4380e42-0a2b-40a4-afb0-a7bff9095316 fwd="213.225.8.56"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-07-31T16:56:10.396407+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> crashed 2022-07-31T16:56:20.217849+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
> with status 12022-07-31T16:56:20.360717+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
> changed from starting to crashed

Comment: i would try with your `build` command. It involves parcel. In one of my projects i just have `"build": "tsc"` and i am fine. By the way, since it involves parcel, maybe buildpack is necessary - https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/parcelconnect/heroku-buildpack-run. Let me know if there is any progress

Comment: Hi I solved this problem by removing the cors pacakge I used. Not sure why heroklu isnt finding the module.

Comment: Ok but that should not be problem. I run my express app on heroku including cors package

Comment: Yea, I imported the cors package, but not used it. Could this be the problem?

Comment: it should not...